# Problem with generating this table

Tags: tables

I would like to write a table in LaTeX using the following command:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
\hline
& ME & RMSE & MAE & MPE & MAPE\\ [0.8ex] 
\hline\hline
DSHW(7, 364) & 26197.65 & 88891.45 & 68771.39  & 1.66 & 4.33 \\
BATS(7, 365) & -46316.36  & 98041.36  & 77747.46  & -2.84  & 4.88\\
\hline
LR+ DSHW(7, 364) & 137934.59 & 165886.30 & 140175.06  & 8.42 & 8.55 \\
LR+ BATS(7, 365) & 40750.45 & 78797.68 & 54005.67 & 2.49 & 3.31 \\
\hline
\caption{Long-term Forecast Performance}
\label{tab:Dfor2}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, it takes a long time to run PDFLaTeX, and shows:

Error: You can't use `\hrule` here except with leaders.

Warning: `Package caption Warning: \label without proper reference on input line 514.

Comment: `\caption` and `\label` should go *outside* the `tabular`.

Comment: Move `\caption` and `\label` between `\end{tabular}` and `\end{table}`.

Comment: Tabular with 6 columns, not 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suggestion with package `booktabs` for rules with better spacing and package `siunitx` for formatting the numbers and aligning them in the columns at the decimal marker. The first column is not changed, because I have not understood it (e.g., is the plus sign a suffix/part of `LR` or it is a "binary" operator?). The line between the data rows is replaced by some extra space to avoid the excessive use of rules.

Often table captions are above the `tabular`, because the tables are read top to down. Package `caption` fixes the caption spacing before and after for table captions above the `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Long-term Forecast Performance}
    \label{tab:Dfor2}
    \begin{tabular}{
      c
      S[table-format=-5.2]
      S[table-format=6.2]
      S[table-format=6.2]
      S[table-format=-1.2]
      S[table-format=1.2]
    }
      \toprule
      & {ME} & {RMSE} & {MAE} & {MPE} & {MAPE} \\
      \midrule
      DSHW(7, 364) & 26197.65 & 88891.45 & 68771.39  & 1.66 & 4.33 \\
      BATS(7, 365) & -46316.36  & 98041.36  & 77747.46  & -2.84  & 4.88 \\
      \addlinespace
      LR+ DSHW(7, 364) & 137934.59 & 165886.30 & 140175.06  & 8.42 & 8.55 \\
      LR+ BATS(7, 365) & 40750.45 & 78797.68 & 54005.67 & 2.49 & 3.31 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks nice! I do not understand what does `S[table-format=-5.2]` mean. So I need to specify a value for each column separately?

Comment: @Jeannie, `S[table-format=-5.2]` would be a column of type S, from `siunitx`, which makes typesetting numbers and units a lot more consistant. The optional argument specifies how many integers(5, with possible negative value), and decimals(2) to make room for. Have a look at the section `tabular material` in the manual for `siunitx` for more information.